# new compiled kernel from 2.4.20 version doesnt get start after an initializing a global structure in sched.c

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler

hi there i'm trying to compile my new kernel from kernel version 2.4.20. Moreover, i have a header file which includes the definitions of structures (one for to define node used by a linked list and a list structure) and two function prototypes which are defined in my new systemcall file `sample.c` . However, when i define a list globally and try to make an allocation in `sched.c` in function `sched_init()` my new kernel version doesnt open. it stucks before get started. here you can see my header file and system call file.

```
/* project_header.h */

#ifndef __LINUX_PROJECT_HEADER_H

#define __LINUX_PROJECT_HEADER_H

#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>

#endif

typedef struct node{

        struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
        long project_pid;
    long project_ticket_number;

}PROJECT_NODE;

typedef struct{

        PROJECT_NODE* head;
        PROJECT_NODE* tail;
        int list_size;

}PROJECT_LIST;

PROJECT_LIST* project_init_list(void);
void project_add_node(PROJECT_LIST*, long);
```

this is my system call `sample` which i implemented. As you can see i had to define functions in here and prototypes are in the `project_header.h` which is called by two system_call files which are `fork.c` and `sched.c`

```
/* sample.c */

#include <linux/sample.h>
#include <linux/project_header.h>

long int maximum_ticket_number=0;
extern PROJECT_LIST* project_list;

PROJECT_LIST* project_init_list(void){

    PROJECT_LIST* list = vmalloc(sizeof(*list));

        list->list_size=0;
        list->head = NULL;
        list->tail = NULL;

    return list;
}

void project_add_node(PROJECT_LIST* list, long id){

     PROJECT_NODE* pnew;

     pnew = vmalloc(sizeof(*pnew));

     pnew->project_pid=id;

    maximum_ticket_number++;
    pnew->project_ticket_number=maximum_ticket_number;

    if(list->list_size==0){ // Assume list is empty

                   list->head = pnew;
                   list->tail = pnew;

                   list->list_size++;
    }
    else {

         list->tail->next = pnew;
         pnew->prev = list->tail;
         list->tail = pnew;

         list->list_size++;
         }

}

asmlinkage void sys_sample(void){ //System call does print the inital list size

        printk("LIST->SIZE = %d\n", project_list->list_size);

    return;
}
```

and this is the part which added into `sched.c`

```
/* sched.c */
.
.

#include <linux/project_header.h>
#include <linux/sample.h>

PROJECT_LIST* project_list; // Create a list globally

extern PROJECT_LIST* project_init_list(void); // Provide to call project_init_list function which returns a list properly

.
.

void __init sched_init(void){

.
.
project_list = vmalloc(sizeof(*project_list)); //Allocate space and initialize the variables of main list
.
.
```

and this is a snapshot of my current situation before kernel get started

[image]

i 'm sure that the problem is in `sched_init()` function but i can't find it. i will be very appreciated if you can help and thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't usually allocate dynamic memory using a `*`.  Also project_list is a pointer so wouldn't it allocate memory the size of the pointer itself?

Comment: actually i dont know how to use `vmalloc` clearly, just searched for a proper example and simple tutorial. but i tried vmalloc many many times in local area rather than global. and whenever i try used to it globally it always get stuck

Comment: Not sure but try replacing `vmalloc(sizeof(*project_list))` with `vmalloc(sizeof(PROJECT_LIST))`.  Just curious, what VM are you using?

Comment: yeap i tried that notation too and it doesnt work. i use `SUN VirtualBox 3.1`

Comment: How about `kmalloc` instead of `vmalloc`.  Typically virtual memory is only allocated in protected mode, and since you are probably in kernel mode you'd need to use kmalloc. Also maybe try inserting a printf operation after your vmalloc to see if it's actually the vmalloc that's causing the problem.  First thing to do is to find out where the problem is being caused.

Comment: Perhaps a printk, not a printf? ;)

Seriously, what have you changed [and why are you compiling a kernel that is 11 years old. What processor are you running it on? Does the processor actually have kernel support?

Comment: but is it possible to see output message of `printk` afer compilation of new kernel which could not be started ?

Comment: @MatsPetersson well this is actually a term project and we have to use this kernel version. on the other hand, i dont use printf and i guess printf doesnt work in kernel space ? and also, i didnt changed something just added some simple code into sched.c to see if it works properly

Comment: vmalloc allocates virtual memory, and virtual memory can only be allocated in protected mode (afaik).  If your kernel has not switched to protected mode then you can't use vmalloc.

Comment: @annoying_squid but i can use vmalloc in sample.c if i define a `structure node` in local area. like `PROJECT_NODE* temp = vmalloc(sizeof(*temp)); temp->project_pid=30;printk("TEMP->PID = %d\n", temp->pid);` and whenever i call `sample()` in my new kernel it prints value truely.

Comment: Does `printk("%d\n",vmalloc(sizeof(*project_list)));` return a non-zero value?

Comment: well how can i understand that it will print a non-zero value while it cant get started ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't REALLY an answer, because this isn't a question that can be answered with the information given. But it's "guidance on how to find out why the kernel doesn't start,and a bit about how the kernel starts".

printk() is the corresponding kernel function to printf() outside of the kernel. Add that at points you think you are getting to, and places where you think it can fail, e.g. if you have "myptr = vmalloc(...);", then

Obviously, if you are so early that the kernel proper hasn't started and that printk may not be available, then you will need to be using out's to the serial port will be the way to debug -

```
  mov $0x3fc, dx
  mov $65, al
  out al, dx
```

will print an 'A' (ascii code 65) to the serial port. Don't hammer more than about 16 characters out at once, they will only come out at 9600 bps or some such.

By the way, the only part of the kernel where you aren't in protected mode is for a few dozen instructions or so.

However, the virtual memory handling doesn't start immediately, and in fact, you may find that it doesn't work until AFTER THE SCHEDULING and the "kswapper" process has started - meaning that you can't use vmalloc in the scheduler - I'm not certain, as this is not a part of the Linux kernel I know that well - but it may be worth looking at kmalloc instead, which is a lower level kernel functionality. Just beware that they aren't exact replacements, so you need to look at the parameters and what they mean, and how to translate. I don't think I've ever used vmalloc() in the kernel - are you sure that's the right function to use?

Comment: well i guess i managed to use kmalloc properly, finally. and thanks for your reply :)